# How to change the decimal separator in C# for raspberry pi with mono?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3b+, c#, mono

I'm working on a C# application that I run on raspberry pi with mono.

I would like to convert a double **A = 0.05** to a double **B = 0,05**.

I succesfully did it on my computer, I changed my Number Decimal Separator for this application and it works very well, but once I try it on the Raspberry pi, it do not work.

```
            //Changing the decimal separator           
            CultureInfo culture;
            culture = (CultureInfo)Application.CurrentCulture.Clone();
            culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
            Application.CurrentCulture = culture;
```

I think that on the raspberry, I can't read the CultureInfo property, I tried to change the langage from fr-FR to en-US but it didn't work...

Have you any idea which could help me ?

Comment: Welcome. *"I succesfully [sic] did it on my computer"* -> What operating system is that?  Was it actually using mono, or was it MS .NET?

Comment: Maybe this post on changing the locale will help:
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/77145/change-default-en-gb-to-en-us-cannot-type-a-pipe-key/77146#77146

Comment: It was working on Visual Studio 2019 on a windows 10 computer. And I already tried to change the locale like this, but it didn't worked